# How to fetch paypal sandbox data to our class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sandbox

I am trying to integrate `paypal sandbox` with my asp.net application ! I have integrated module and i have redirected to `paypal sandbox` site ! You can login to sandbox and make payment ! Paypal focus redirects to my return URL ! Now the problem is I don't know what `paypal sandbox` returns with 'return URL' and even I am new with sandbox so I don't know how to manage the redirected data ! Kindly Inform me ! Thank you !

I have tried to download demos ! But in demos most of uses their own dll ! They are not providing class definition so I am little bit confused !

Comment: The returned stuffs should be in the `form` data.

Comment: But how to fetch ? Can you give a link or sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

At first, check the paypal docs which fields are returned. As Mr. Disappointment guessed, the data will probably be returned as form data in a HTTP POST request.

You can check the request and the data with fiddler.

To access form data within an ASP.NET app, you simply use the [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) object:

```
var field = Request["fieldName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Log into your sandbox account, then click on Documentation --> Sample Code then click the Integration Wizard link to generate all the sample code that you need.

The return URL will have two URL Params:

token,
payerId

I am using MVC so my Controller Method signature looks like this:

```
public ActionResult PaypalOrderConfirmation(string token, string payerId)
```

but you could just use e.g. Request.QueryString("token"); //Is that right it's been a while...

Then you need to "Commit the payment"

```
NVPCodec nvpCodec = new NVPCodec();
string returnMessage;

bool success = PayPal.CommitPayment(someTotal, token, payerId, out nvpCodec, out returnMessage);
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

```
public static bool CommitPayment(decimal finalPaymentAmount, string token, string payerId, out NVPCodec nvpCodec, out string returnMessage)
        {
            nvpCodec = new NVPCodec();
            returnMessage = "";

            bool success = new NVPAPICaller().ConfirmPayment(finalPaymentAmount.ToString(), token, payerId, ref nvpCodec, ref returnMessage);

            return success;
        }
```

I will go have another look on paypal for the download code and add it to this post if I find it.